# SQL Server slow when linking to Access

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access

I'm have a table in SQL Server that I linked to Access and I noticed after doing that, now my queries are noticeably slow. I would really like to just un-link the table but there are some access programs built that needs this table, so that not an option. Does anyone know why this could be occurring or how to fix this. I have been researching this issue and have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

Most selects if just based on one table should perform rather well. However updates to tables do tend to run slow and those should be converted to pass-thought.

For complex reports based on a query that involves several tables and especially those with aggregate functions should be converted to a VIEW. You then simply link the report to the view and performance should be just fine. This setup also means that any "where" clause you pass to the report will work and work well without having modify your existing VBA filter code (the filter WILL ONLY pull down records based on that filter from sql server – not the whole table).

So for update queries that have to operate on large tables, then simply use a pass-though.

If you have "on the fly" SQL code in VBA that needs to update lots of rows, then you can create server side sql using this:

```
Dim qdfPass       As DAO.QueryDef 

Set qdfPass = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass") 
qdfPass.SQL = "my server side sql goes here"
qdfPass.Execute
```

You can also use the above for pass-through to retrieve records like this:

```
Dim qdfPass       As DAO.QueryDef 
Dim rstData       As DAO.RecordSet

Set qdfPass = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass") 
qdfPass.SQL = "my server side sql goes here"
set rstData =  qdfPass.OpenRecordSet
```

So forms and reports can REMAIN bound to linked tables. And passing a where clause will filter (not whole table is pulled).

So simple selects on tables should work well but when you introduce joins and aggregate quires, or have to update lots of rows then using the above pass-though idea will give you 100% server side performance which should be VERY fast indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proper indexes on the table?  Probably a silly question, but some people don't know how to use indexes properly.